# Find unique attribute update children value with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to update the following:

```
<a data-fb="4dfsdgdsgsdfgsdfgcf08" class="fb-like" href="#">
<span class="like-icon">Likes:</span> 10</a>
```

I wish to update the value '10' with a result returned from a web service, I have the result stored in a variable called fbNumber. The data-fb attribute is unique so I wish to search for this and update the value.

Comment: If the `data-fb` value is unique, why not use the `id` attribute and use `getElementById()` to reference it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `.replace` seems to be sufficient here. You can get the current contents using the `.html` method, and replace any sequence of numbers found within with your new number:

```
var fbNumber = 23;

$("a[data-fb='4dfsdgdsgsdfgsdfgcf08']").html(function(i,v){
    return v.replace( /([0-9]+)/, fbNumber );
});​​​​​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GbqJg/

Comment: Bah, had something similar with .html but forgot [] brackets, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("[data-fb='4dfsdgdsgsdfgsdfgcf08']").html("<span class=\"like-icon\">Likes:</span> "+ fbNumber);
```